# How to do autoplay(image) in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 images. I want to show one by one through auto play with various time delay(first one 3 seconds,second one 5 seconds,third one 7 seconds). Finally i want to loop it.

I have no idea to do it. Please share ideas with me for it.

Comment: look at the source code for http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ - lots of ideas inside there

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this:

```
function f1(){
  //Do stuff
  setTimeout(function(){f2();}, 200);
}

function f2(){
  //Do stuff
  setTimeout(function(){f3();}, 200);
}

function f3(){
  //Do stuff
  setTimeout(function(){f1();}, 200);
}
```